# Is it possible to coppy weblogic and it's domain from linux to windows using some tools?

Tags: java, server, weblogic, config, clone

I searched about cloning or copying weblogic and it's domain, and found 2 ways that I think is the most nearest to my question.
1, [packing and unpacking a weblogic domain](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e14144/intro.htm#WLDPU162)
2, [Creating Extension Templates](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e14139/appbuild.htm#g1075657) .
There is weblogic  12.2.4 installed on Linux server and I want to coppy it's configuration and domain and create my own instance with exact configuration.
If it's possible, pleas give me solution or some clues and key-word to search more.
And do I need to change some configs by hand or provided tool does everything?
Is copying domain different from copying weblogic configuration?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a domain with the same configuration, but on Windows, you should use [Weblogic Deploy Tooling](https://github.com/oracle/weblogic-deploy-tooling).

The first step is to install Oracle Weblogic on your windows machine(s).

The second step is to use the [discoverydomain.sh](https://github.com/oracle/weblogic-deploy-tooling/blob/master/site/discover.md) to introspect the domain, which is running on Linux.

The previous step will generate a [model](https://github.com/oracle/weblogic-deploy-tooling/blob/master/site/model.md) in YAML, which represents your Linux domain as code and then you will have to customize it with proper values for Weblogic's user's passwords, data sources, etc.

Once you have the model ready, you can run [createdomain.cmd](https://github.com/oracle/weblogic-deploy-tooling/blob/master/site/create.md) on Windows to create the domain. By the way, if your domain is distributed on several machines you will have to run pack and unpack after creating the domain with Weblogic Deploy Tooling because it only works on the node, which will host the AdminServer.

Here you have an example about using Weblogic Deploy Tooling with Ansible to create a domain with SOA https://github.com/textanalyticsman/ansible-soa-wldt

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is theoretically possible to copy `$DOMAIN_HOME`  (WebLogic domain) to or from Windows.

However, I would NOT copy the `$WL_HOME` directory. Here a fresh installation is the only way.

As you mention the tool recommended by Oracle would be `pack` and `unpack`. With the assumption, that there is no WebLogic security realm configured.

Another option would be to create a new domain (preferable with the same name) with the Configuration Wizard  and then copy the XML-fragments from the old $DOMAIN_HOME/config/* files in the fresh domain. Watch out for the  encrypted passwords. Don't mix the encrypted fields in the old a new domain.

Another option would to use Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2). In this case, you can copy your files 1:1. `$JAVA_HOME`, `$WL_HOME` and `$DOMAIN_HOME`  in one go. You WebLogic Server will start without any problems, except some DNS-Names or IP-Addresses issues.

Comment: WSL is not supported by Oracle to run Weblogic unless you want to play with some experimental setup.